# Extracting page titles and contributors from MediaWiki XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-2.7, mediawiki, elementtree

I have a very large (7GB) MediaWiki XML dump, which consists of records of each change made to each page of the Wiki. I am trying to record which users have contributed to each page, and so I want to extract that from the XML.

The XML looks something like:

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/">
 <page>
  <title>Unique Page title</title>
  <id>11</id>
  <restrictions>sysop</restrictions>
  <revision>
    <id>11</id>
    <timestamp>2005-10-26T02:23:03Z</timestamp>
    <contributor>
      <ip>MediaWiki default</ip>
    </contributor>
    <text xml:space="preserve">i</text>
  </revision>
 </page>
 <page> ... </page>
 <page> ... </page>
 ...
</mediawiki>
```

For a file this size, I believe I need to use iterparse. For now, I'm just trying to print out the title, but when I run the following code, it prints "None".

```
NS = '{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/}'
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
with open('XMLFile.xml') as f:
    for event, elem in iterparse(f):
        if elem.tag == NS + 'page':
            for node in elem:
                if node.tag == NS + 'title':
                    print node.text()
        elem.clear()
```

Comment: [mediawiki-utilities](https://pythonhosted.org/mediawiki-utilities/) is supposed to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `None` when printing the text content of the `title` element because you are using [`elem.clear()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.clear) "too early". By default, [`iterparse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) only generates "end" events. When the "end" event for `page` is emitted, all its subelements, including `title`, have already been cleared (emptied).

If `elem.clear()` in the code in the question is moved just one indentation level (four spaces) to the right, it will work as expected. Another way to make your code work is to change `iterparse(f)` to `iterparse(f, events=["start"])`.

And `node.text()` should be `node.text`.

See http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm for more details on `iterparse()`.

---

Assume that the XML dump (mw.xml) looks like this:

```xml
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/">
  <page>
    <title>Unique Page title 1</title>
    <id>11</id>
    <restrictions>sysop</restrictions>
    <revision>
      <id>11</id>
      <timestamp>2005-10-26T02:23:03Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
       <username>Alice</username>
      </contributor>
      <text xml:space="preserve">i</text>
    </revision>
  </page>

  <page>
    <title>Unique Page title 2</title>
    <id>11</id>
    <restrictions>sysop</restrictions>
    <revision>
      <id>11</id>
      <timestamp>2005-10-26T02:23:03Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
       <username>Bob</username>
      </contributor>
      <text xml:space="preserve">j</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

Here is a suggestion on how you can get the title and contributor:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

NS = '{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/}'

with open('mw.xml') as f:
    for event, elem in iterparse(f):
        if elem.tag == '{0}page'.format(NS):
            title = elem.find("{0}title".format(NS))
            contr = elem.find(".//{0}username".format(NS))

            if title is not None:
                print title.text
            if contr is not None:
                print contr.text

            elem.clear()
```

Output:

```
Unique Page title 1 
Alice
Unique Page title 2 
Bob
```

I'm assuming that you want the username of the contributor. According to the latest [XML Schema](http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8.xsd), `contributor` can contain `username`, `ip`, and/or `id` child elements (this is true also for the 0.3 version of the schema).

Answer (score 3):

Try pulling the 'title' elements directly out during iterative parsing instead of doing a secondary loop:

```
NS = '{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/}'
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
with open('XMLFile.xml') as f:
    for event, elem in iterparse(f):
            if elem.tag == NS + 'title':
                print elem.text
            elem.clear()
```

seems to work for me.

Comment: I need to make sure that the title element and the contributor both refer to the same revision - that is, that they both have the same parent element. It looks like this solution doesn't do that, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in using Python and iterparse, but generally, the way you'd do this with an iterative XML parser would be like this:

- Outside the parsing loop, set up variables to store the current page title and list of contributors.
- Inside the loop, whenever a `page` tag is opened, reset the variables.
- When you encounter a `title` tag, set the page title variable to its contents.
- When you encounter a `contributor` tag, add its contents to the list of contributors.
- When the `page` tag is closed, output the collected title and the list of contributors.